# How can we configure the internal Jackson mapper when using RestTemplate?

Tags: spring, jackson

I want to update the SerializationConfig.Feature... properties of the jackson mapper used by Spring RestTemplate, Any idea how I can get to it or where I can/should configure it.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

The default `RestTemplate` constructor registers a set of `HttpMessageConverter`s:

```
this.messageConverters.add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
this.messageConverters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
this.messageConverters.add(new ResourceHttpMessageConverter());
this.messageConverters.add(new SourceHttpMessageConverter());
this.messageConverters.add(new XmlAwareFormHttpMessageConverter());
if (jaxb2Present) {
    this.messageConverters.add(new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter());
}
if (jacksonPresent) {
    this.messageConverters.add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
}
if (romePresent) {
    this.messageConverters.add(new AtomFeedHttpMessageConverter());
    this.messageConverters.add(new RssChannelHttpMessageConverter());
}
```

The `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` in turns, creates `ObjectMapper` instance directly. You can either find this converter and replace `ObjectMapper` or register a new one before it. This should work:

```
@Bean
public RestOperations restOperations() {
    RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
    //this is crucial!
    rest.getMessageConverters().add(0, mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
    return rest;
}

@Bean
public MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter() {
    MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setObjectMapper(myObjectMapper());
    return converter;
}

@Bean
public ObjectMapper myObjectMapper() {
    //your custom ObjectMapper here
}
```

In XML it is something along these lines:

```
<bean id="restOperations" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <util:list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.XmlAwareFormHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="objectMapper" ref="customObjectMapper"/>
            </bean>
        </util:list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="customObjectMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper"/>
```

Note that the transition isn't really 1:1 - I have to explicitly create `messageConverters` list in XML while with `@Configuration` approach I could reference existing one and simply modify it. But this should work.

Comment: i would be grateful if you could translate this to XML.  really want to try this but not sure how to configure it.  many thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this is just due to a version difference, but I believe the correct name for the Jackson converter class is MappingJackson*2*HttpMessageConverter

Comment: I would probably avoid adding a new mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter in the beginning of the existing default ones, but replace the existing Jackson message converter instead. Otherwise you end up having 2 Jackson message converters in the list.

Comment: I tried adding it at index 0 and I got some very strange JSON parse exceptions. Removing the existing worked better like @mvogiatzis suggested

Comment: I was need to change `RestOperations -> RestTemplate` in `@Bean` definition to make this works

Comment: Shouldn't  myObjectMapper() and mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter()) be called by requesting a parameter in the @Bean methods?

Comment: Finally, the `add(0, ...)` fixed my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 34):

If you are not using Spring IOC, you can do something like this (Java 8):

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
// configure your ObjectMapper here

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();    

MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
messageConverter.setPrettyPrint(false);
messageConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().removeIf(m -> m.getClass().getName().equals(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class.getName()));
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(messageConverter);
```

Comment: why do you need to remove and re-add when you can just find it iterating?

Comment: restTemplate.getMessageConverters().removeIf(m -> m.getClass().isAssignableFrom(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class));

Answer (score 15):

RestTemplate will initialize its default message converters. You should replace the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` with your own bean, which should use the object mapper you want to use. This worked for me:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    //find and replace Jackson message converter with our own
    for (int i = 0; i < restTemplate.getMessageConverters().size(); i++) {
        final HttpMessageConverter<?> httpMessageConverter = restTemplate.getMessageConverters().get(i);
        if (httpMessageConverter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter){
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().set(i, mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        }
    }

    return restTemplate;
}

@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setObjectMapper(myObjectMapper());
    return converter;
}

@Bean
public ObjectMapper myObjectMapper() {
    // return your own object mapper
}
```

Comment: It seems it's important to name the method something like `myObjectMapper()` but not just `objectMapper()`.  For some reason it seems the method is never called and you get the default `ObjectMapper`.

Comment: This worked, but seems there is a typo in the answer? `restTemplate.getMessageConverters().set(i, mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter);` should be `restTemplate.getMessageConverters().set(i, mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());` (note the parenthesis in mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(), making it a method call instead of a reference)

Comment: True, or you can alternatively add the `mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` as a parameter to the `restTemplate` function use it as is.

Comment: you dont have to create a new one, you can just set your mapper if (httpMessageConverter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter){
                ((MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter)httpMessageConverter).setObjectMapper(mapper());
            }

Comment: In Java8 you can use streams or Java14 you can use pattern matching for instanceof. Otherwise nice declarative solution.

Answer (score 12):

To complete the other answers: if your `ObjectMapper` just registers a Jackson `Module` with custom serializers/deserializers, you might want to register your module directly on the existing `ObjectMapper` from `RestTemplate`'s default `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` as follows (example without DI but the same applies if using DI):

```
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addSerializer(...);
    module.addDeserializer(...);

    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter = restTemplate.getMessageConverters().stream()
                    .filter(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class::isInstance)
                    .map(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class::cast)
                    .findFirst().orElseThrow( () -> new RuntimeException("MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter not found"));
    messageConverter.getObjectMapper().registerModule(module);
```

This will allow you to complete the configuration of the original `ObjectMapper` (as done by Spring's `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`), instead of replacing it.

Answer (score 10):

Using Spring Boot, it is as simple as:

```
RestTemplate template = new RestTemplateBuilder()
                            .additionalMessageConverters(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(objectMapper))
                            .build()
```

(Tested with Spring Boot 2.2.1)

Comment: With this approach your `RestTemplate` will have only one `MessageConverter`: `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`. But I still like it

Comment: `additionalMessageConverters` is not really additive. It will perform a full replacement and you'll loose other converters. It's stated on its docstring. (It adds to the builder's list of converters, which will fully replace the instance's)

Comment: @Ming To be more precise, `additionalMessageConverters` will not replace already configured converters on the **builder**. "Any converters configured on the builder will replace RestTemplate's default converters" means that the `RestTemplate` instance produced by `RestTemplateBuilder.build()` method will not have any other converters except those configured on the builder. So, as soon as you configure **any** `HttpMessageConverter` on the builder instance, they will replace default `RestTemplate` conveters. This could be circumvented by calling `builder.defaultMessageConverters()` first.

Comment: Also, Spring Boot has already configured `RestTemplateBuilder` bean in `prototype` scope. This bean is already configured with default converters (the list includes all `HttpMessageConverter`s from `HttpMessageConverters` bean, that are even better than `RestTemplate`'s default). Also the bean has all `RestTemplateCustomizer` beans applied. So, you can just inject `RestTemplateBuilder` into your component and then `additionalMessageConverters` would really **add** converters, because at the moment of the calling the list would not be empty.

Answer (score 0):

To just update the SerializationConfig.Feature using the current ObjectMapper:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate =  new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().forEach(mc -> {
            if (mc instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter ) {
                //whatever you want to change
                ((MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) mc).getObjectMapper().setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
            }
        });
```