# How to configure MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter while using spring annotation-based configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, jackson

I was unreasonable enough to went into configuring spring beans via annotations and not pure xml beans and now I'm facing the consequences.

I configure REST channels using

```xml
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Now I want simply configure the `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` to output to JSON only this fields that have non-null values. I've tried the following:

```xml
<bean id="jsonHttpMessageConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="prefixJson" value="false" />
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
    <property name="objectMapper">
        <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper">
            <property name="serializationInclusion" value="NON_NULL"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The beans gets created, but another instance of converter is created and used in channels. So I've tried the way with `@Configuration` and `@Bean` described in [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381665/how-can-we-configure-the-internal-jackson-mapper-when-using-resttemplate), but still json serialization uses its own configuration.

Finally I've tried to inject the mapper via

```
@Autowired
private MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter jacksonConverter;
```

but I've ended with `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`. So now I'm out of options and therefore I'm asking for any ideas here. How to controll and configure the mapper used by framework?

Comment: Try changing the name of the wired field to `jsonHttpMessageConverter` like `@Autowired
private MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter jsonHttpMessageConverter;`

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use the [`WebMvcConfigurer.configureMessageConverters()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html#configureMessageConverters(java.util.List)) method:

> Configure the HttpMessageConverters to use [...] If no message converters are added to the list, default converters are added instead.

With `@Configuration` you have:

```
@Configuration
class MvcConf extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    protected void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(converter());
        addDefaultHttpMessageConverters(converters);
    }

    @Bean
    MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter converter() {
        MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter()
        //do your customizations here...
        return converter;
    }
}
```

Call to `addDefaultHttpMessageConverters()` is required because the defaults are not applied when using custom converters.

**IMPORTANT NOTE**  You must remove `@EnableWebMvc` for your converters to be configured if you extend WebMvcConfigurationSupport.

Comment: still, in my case, only another instance of MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter is created and it is not the one that is used afterwards

Comment: It seems to depend on the order of adding your converter vs default ones. When I add my own converter first like described above it works for me.

Comment: Also, don't forget the **versions** must be compatible. I am using Spring 4.* and I tried for hours to set it up with Jackson 1.* - didn't work. Then, I found out, they changed the artifact to com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind in Jasckson 2.*. I changed the dependendencies -> worked like a charm (without configureMessageConverters) ;)

Comment: Imprtant note was my life-saver as well... but I'm mad at Spring for this... where in the docs is such a crucial thing clearly spelled out??

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - it's spelled out right there: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-auto-configuration

Comment: @ETL Irrelevant... that's Spring Boot documentation.

Comment: The important note saved me as well and I was using `@Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)`.  Instead of importing my configuration class just needed to extend `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration`

Comment: `Cannot resolve method 'add(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter)'`. `Cannot resolve method 'addDefaultHttpMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>>)'`. `Cannot resolve symbol 'MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter'`. P.S. Yes, I've added all imports.

Comment: @DanubianSailor did you ever get around this?

Comment: For some unknown reason, this doesn't work for me. Might it be because I have classes extending `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` andother classes extending `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`?

Debugging when app starts up shows in both cases, code is executed by Spring. But still not an objectmapper with my configuration when calling controllers.

Comment: @Wrench comment was the solution for me. I had put a WebMvcConfigurer in my classpath to solve a component scan problem a few weeks ago and now it is messing with my annotated beans.

Comment: Hi @Tomasz I tried in my XML configured MVC, but at server start time, I'm getting this: _org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [com/acc/ws/rest/config/WebConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set_

Answer (score 27):

The customization of the spring mvc servlet configuration only in java code can be accomplished in multiple ways.

The simplest one seems to be extending your `@Configuration` annotated class with `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ApplicationSpringConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters( List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters ) {
        converters.add(converter());
    }

    @Bean
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter() {
        // [...]
    }
}
```

Notice that this is lot like the example provided by the answer of *Tomasz Nurkiewicz*.

However using `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` instead of `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` is more appropriate for Advanced Customizations. That was the case if you needed to also add the default converters.

See the Spring documentation [Customizing the Provided Configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-customize)

Comment: Why the method `converter()` has to be marked with `@Bean`?

Comment: JavaDoc:that adding converters to the list, turns off default converter registration. To simply add a converter without impacting default registration, consider using the method extendMessageConverters(java.util.List) instead.

Comment: @MikhailBatcer - The `@Bean` annotation is placed so you can use this method returned object from within your container (spring) context. Also see question for answer contextualization.

Answer (score -1):

The following solution is for Spring 4.3, (non-boot) where it was necessary to address `fetch=FetchType.LAZY` by adding a module to the Jackson converters. A similar technique can be used to modify converters in any way, including removal and recreation.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

    for (HttpMessageConverter<?> mc : converters){
         if (mc instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter || mc instanceof MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter) {
            ((AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter) mc).getObjectMapper().registerModule(new Hibernate5Module());
        }
    }
    return;
 }
```

In this case,

- the `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` has a lot of other configuration in it and I wanted to avoid another configuration class.
- Using `extendMessageConverters` enabled access to the automatically-configured Jackson classes without losing the configuration of all other message converters, which is what `configureMessageConverters` would have done.
- Using `registerModule`you can simply add the needed `Hibernate5Module` to the existing converters.
- The module was added to both the JSON and XML processors