# How to pass data to browser javascript from Spring MVC controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services, spring-mvc, browser

I would like to pass data from Spring MVC to javascript but I am not sure what is the best way to do it.

Say, in javascript, there an array

```
var myArray = new Array();
```

In backend java, there is an array

```
int[] myArray = new int[100];
```

What is the best way to pass this array to the front end javascript. What about multiple arrays as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to json-ify your array.  Best way is to have your view use the built in MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.

Might want to look at this thread:

[How to configure MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter while using spring annotation-based configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650196/how-to-configure-mappingjacksonhttpmessageconverter-while-using-spring-annotatio)