# Difference between WebMvcConfigurationSupport and WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I would like to add resource handlers. In the forum they use `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?116068-How-to-configure-lt-mvc-resources-gt-mapping-to-take-precedence-over-RequestMapping&p=384066#post384066

and docs say `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/EnableWebMvc.html

What's the difference and which one to use? Both has the `addResourceHandlers` method I need.

This is my current class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    public @Override void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources");
    }

    public @Bean TilesViewResolver tilesViewResolver() {
        return new TilesViewResolver();
    }

    public @Bean TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
        TilesConfigurer ret = new TilesConfigurer();
        ret.setDefinitions(new String[] { "classpath:tiles.xml" });
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The answer is in the doc you referenced above:

> If the customization options of WebMvcConfigurer do not expose
>   something you need to configure, consider removing the @EnableWebMvc
>   annotation and extending directly from WebMvcConfigurationSupport
>   overriding selected @Bean methods

In short, if @EnableWebMvc works for you, there is no need to look any further.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to this ?

Answer (score 7):

if you use ConfigurationSupport class get ready mind numbing hardwork when trying to serve static resources, because it does not work.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same thing.. is there a workaround here?  Adding resourcehandlers don't seem to have any effect, they seem to be ignored, or at least that's what I'm seeing..

Comment: @MarkD use WebMvcConfigurerAdapter and it will work flawlessly

Comment: ya except I need to use some features not in it - i.e. override the     requestMappingHandlerMapping() method which doesn't seem to be in the ConfigurerAdapter?

Answer (score 7):

I was recently solving this very same problem when configuring converters and it resulted in [quite a long post](https://virgo47.wordpress.com/2020/05/14/spring-boot-and-http-message-converters-no-jackson-no-defaults/).

By default Spring Boot uses its implementation of `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` and does a lot of auto-magic including finding all the `WebMvcConfigurer` and using them. There is one implementation provided by Boot already and you may add more. This results in seemingly confusing behaviour when the list of converters coming to `configureMessageConverters` in your implementation of `WebMvcConfigurer` is already pre-populated from previous configurer.

These types (`WebMvcConfigurationSupport` and `WebMvcConfigurer`) have also strikingly similar interface - but the first does NOT implement the other. The point is:

***Support** class searches for **configurers** and uses them + does something on its own.*

If you extend from `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` you take over the configuration and while there are some things available that are not in `WebMvcConfigurer` (like `addDefaultHttpMessageConverters`) there is also tons of code from `EnableWebMvcConfiguration` and `DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration` that does not happen.

Both extending `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` or `WebMvcConfigurer` (not sure both at once makes much sense) have their valid usages, but with extending the support class you take over the process much more and lose a lot of "opinionated" Spring Boot functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Its better to extend WebMvcConfigurationSupport. It provides more customization options and also 
works fine with

```
configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters)
```

cause you can add these convertors using

```
addDefaultHttpMessageConverters(converters);
```

that is not available with  WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.

Click [here] [How to configure MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter while using spring annotation-based configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650196/how-to-configure-mappingjacksonhttpmessageconverter-while-using-spring-annotatio)

If you extend WebMvcConfigurerAdapter, it behaves strangely with configuring Jackson and Jaxb.
That happened with me !!!

Comment: Yes you are right. Same problems here ... because alle the common converters are missing without calling `addDefaultHttpMessageConverters(converters);`

Comment: This depends really. If you extend from `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` many things implemented in the default Spring Boot subclasses stop working. E.g. beans are not included automatically.