# Setting Jackson feature WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS not working in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, serialization, jackson

I set `spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS=false` in the Spring Boot config but the Jackson serializer still produces `[1942,4,2]` instead of `"1942-04-02"` for a `DateTime` value.

**Some debugging snapshots**

- In `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration.StandardJackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer#customize` there's

  `configureFeatures(builder, this.jacksonProperties.getSerialization());`

  which shows that "WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS" -> "false"
- Then a bit later in `org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder#configure` there's this loop

  `for (Object feature : this.features.keySet()) {
    configureFeature(objectMapper, feature, this.features.get(feature));
  }`

  and again `this.features` says "WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS" -> "false"
- Yet during serialzation of a `DateTime` `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.ser.JSR310FormattedSerializerBase#useTimestamp` says false because `provider.isEnabled(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)` returns false.

**Attempts at fixing**

- Out of despair I replaced `spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS=false` with `spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=false` because I found that mentioned in a lot of places (even though the [Boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper) doesn't hint at this). What about this? They seem to be synonyms - no effect.
- While writing this question SO suggested [WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS not woking on Spring boot 1.3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38152180/131929). The answer says to replace `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` with `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`. While this does help indeed I fail to understand why so.

Comment: This last remark is the actual answer to the original question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Spring Boot takes the presence of a `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` bean as an indication that you want to take complete control of the configuration of Spring MVC. You'd typically end up with such a bean by using `@EnableWebMvc` but you could also declare your own bean or configuration class that is a `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`.

If you subclass `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` rather than `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` you're making an additive change to Spring Boot's auto-configuration of Spring MVC rather than taking over completely.

Part of Spring Boot's auto-configuration of Spring MVC is to configure it to use the auto-configured `ObjectMapper` for HTTP message conversion. If you switch off Boot's auto-configuration of Spring MVC, it will use its own, separate `ObjectMapper` that is unaffected by any `spring.jackson.*` configuration settings.

Comment: To clarify, you should remove `@EnableWebMvc` annotation too. It solved my issue