# Spring boot jackson non_null property not working

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

I am using Spring boot **1.5.7-RELEASE**.

I am trying to set **global non null** Jackson property in my application.

but it is not working.

I have tried both in application.properties and bootstrap.properties but not working.

```
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=NON_NULL
spring.jackson.serialization-inclusion=NON_NULL
```

but when I applied on class level, it is working fine.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.NON_NULL)
```

Comment: do you mean https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813319/enforce-not-null-field-in-json-object?

Comment: My concern is without annotating the field, through properties file is this possible

Comment: make it lowercase spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_null

Comment: I was caught by same problem caused by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45609569/setting-jackson-feature-write-dates-as-timestamps-not-working-in-spring-boot

Comment: @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL), this is not working for me. Spring boot version 2.1.4

Answer (score 11):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper) the correct answer is:

```
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_null
```

(note the lowercase non_null - this may be the cause of your problem)

Edit:
I've created a simple Spring Boot 1.5.7.RELEASE project with only the following two compile dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then I added the following controller and response classes (using Lombok to skip some boilerplate code):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/jackson")
public class JacksonTestController {

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public Response test() {
        val response = new Response();
        response.setField1("");

        return response;
    }
}

@Data
class Response {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private Integer field3;
}
```

Finally, I configured Jackson as per the documentation, ran the application, and navigated to `http://localhost:8080/jackson/test`. The result was (as expected):

```
{"field1":""}
```

After that, I dug into Spring Boot's source code and discovered that Spring uses class `org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` to create instances of `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`. I then put a breakpoint in method `public <T extends ObjectMapper> T build()` of the aforementioned builder class and ran my application in debug mode.

I discovered that there are 8 instances of `ObjectMapper` created during application startup and only one of them is configured using contents of `application.properties` file. The OP never specified how exactly he was using the serialization, so it's possible his code referred to one of the other 7 object mappers available.

At any rate, the only way to ensure that all object mappers in the application are configured to serialize only non-null properties is to create one's own copy of class `org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` and either hard code that option as default or customize the class to read `application.properties` during every call to its constructor or build method.

Comment: My version seems to prefer NON_NULL

Comment: Hey how did you figure out that there are 8 instances of ObjectMapper? Is there a way do debug how many instances of a certain object are there at runtime using Intellij or Eclipse? Thanks

Comment: I wrote that in my response: "After that I dug into Spring Boot's source code and discovered that Spring uses class org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder to create instances of com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper. I then put a breakpoint in method public <T extends ObjectMapper> T build() of aforementioned builder class and run my application in debug mode."

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I'm late to the party but It may help someone.

Extend WebMvcConfigurationSupport class and customize the Springboot configuration the way you want.

```
@Configuration
public class Config extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport{

    @Override
    protected void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        converter.setObjectMapper(mapper);
        converters.add(converter);
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just dealing with the settings in `application.properties` not taking either.  In my case, there was an abstract config class I was extending which defined an `ObjectMapper` bean that had totally different settings.  So I had to override it.

What brought me to the place of finding that was using the `/beans` Actuator endpoint that Spring Boot apps have, and searching for '`ObjectMapper`'.  It revealed an instance I didn't realize was being created.