# confuse between WebMvcConfigurationSupport and WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I would like to add resource handlers using WebMvcConfigurerAdapter in Windows, but in Linux it doesn't work, so I add `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`.

After debug and test I find two bean will be create in both OS, but the override function of `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` will be executed only at Windows and the override function of `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` will be executed only at Linux.

I can't find out the reason. The two configuration classes are shown below:

```
@Configuration
public class JxWebAppConfigurer  extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
   @Override
   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
     registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("file:"+System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/main/webapp/");
     super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
   }
}
```

This is the other one:

```
@Configuration
public class JxWebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
       registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("file:"+System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/main/webapp/");
       super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
   }
}
```

@EnalbeMvc is already been added at the main class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between WebMvcConfigurationSupport and WebMvcConfigurerAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17898606/difference-between-webmvcconfigurationsupport-and-webmvcconfigureradapter)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned [in the @EnableWebMvc Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/EnableWebMvc.html):

> Adding this annotation to an @Configuration class imports the Spring
>   MVC configuration from WebMvcConfigurationSupport

{..}

> To customize the imported configuration, implement the interface
>   WebMvcConfigurer or more likely extend the empty method base class
>   WebMvcConfigurerAdapter and override individual methods

{..}

> If WebMvcConfigurer does not expose some advanced setting that needs
>   to be configured, consider removing the @EnableWebMvc annotation and
>   extending directly from WebMvcConfigurationSupport

So in effect either:

1. `@EnableWebMvc` + extending `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` (suggested first option)
2. Extending directly from `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` (fallback alternative for full control)

(on both cases needed `@Configuration`)

Comment: Ok，I read the documents last night and test again, I find another @EnableWebMvc that I don't find before,it's the problems, one @@EnableWebMvc is enough but I add several and ignore it.

Comment: If you find this answer useful please consider upvoting/accepting it.

Comment: I have another question: Can I extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport(or DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration,what's the difference between them?) and still use WebAutoConfiguration? Or there is another way to add resourcehandlers and don't switch off  WebAutoConfiguration? Many thanks~

Answer (score 3):

The alternative solution for `org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`is  `org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport` (I am using Spring Framework 5.0.2.RELEASE).

`WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` has been deprecated.

Comment: This is not true - alternative for now deprecated `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` is interface `WebMvcConfigurer` with its default methods now. Javadoc says that as well. Extending from `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` has side effects; behavior is different.

Answer (score 1):

I know the reasons. As mentioned above,you should choose one select(extends `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter+@EnableWebMvc` or just extends  `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` ) ;

Never use `@EnableWebMvc` and extending  `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` 
together!!

if use spring-boot's `@EnableAutoConfiguration` ,you can just extends  `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` and don't use `@EnableMvc`

Answer (score 0):

Behavior differences on OS are not clear to me (classpath order?) so I'll just talk about `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` vs `WebMvcConfigurer`. Let's start with `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` that implements `WebMvcConfigurer`, but now is deprecated because the interface has the functionality via default methods.

Now to the "support" (extending `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`) vs "configurer" (implementing `WebMvcConfigurer`). These classes have very similar methods but it works roughly like this:

**Support** component finds all the **configurers** and combines them into the final configuration.

I recently wrote [quite a long post](https://virgo47.wordpress.com/2020/05/14/spring-boot-and-http-message-converters-no-jackson-no-defaults/) about this with [code examples](https://github.com/virgo47/spring-message-converters-demo) and I recommend experimenting with small Spring Boot applications and debug them - it's eye opening.

Boot has a default implementation of `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` and it does a lot of stuff - including finding beans implementing `WebMvcConfigurer` and using them. If you take over and implement the support class, Boot will find it, disables the default one and you're in full control. But then a lot of default auto-magic is gone and you have to use it if needed.