# Swagger. "No handler found" error (SimpleUrlHandlerMapping not injected)

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox-boot-starter

When I try to access the Swagger UI page (`.../service-name/swagger-ui.html`) I receive `No handler found for GET ...` error.

[image]

I did some research and found out that `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` bean, which is required for swagger page to work not created by Spring. Here is an example of the **correctly** working service, breakpoint at `BeanFactoryUtils.java:378`:
[image]

[image]

And here is an example of the **actual** behavior of my app, where the needed bean was not created:
[image]

[image: Bean not found]

These two applications use the same spring and swagger version, also, swagger configurations are completely similar. Can you help me to find out why is it happening? The weird part here is even if I reset my branch to the date when I am 100% sure that swagger-ui worked, I still receive this error, maybe some internal Spring *caching* is involved?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61814446/11433078). My app had two configurations based on `WebMvcConfigurer` and `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`, this caused some issues during the context creation. The solution here is that you need to use only one type of configuration