# Deserialize requestParam enum case insensitive in spring boot using jackson

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, enums, jackson

I'm having below api

```
  @GetMapping(value = "/employees")
    public List<Employee> getEmployees(
        @RequestParam(value = "mode", required = false) final EmployeeMode mode) {
        //calling service from here
    }
```

I'm having EmployeeMode enum as requestParam.

```
public enum EmployeeMode {

    REGULAR,
    ALL,
    TEMPROARY
}
```

I want to accept request with case insensitive. Tried with `@JsonAlias`, `@JsonCreator` and `objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_ENUMS, true);` and `spring.jackson.mapper.accept-case-insensitive-enums: true`. nothing worked for me.

I'm using spring boot 2.5.5.

How to accept case insensitive request with requestParam? And if requestParam is empty/null, want to set default enum as ALL.

Comment: *And if requestParam is empty/null, want to set default enum as ALL.* I think, that can you only manage with a custom deserializer

Comment: Which library do you use to deserialize the requests? `jackson` or `gson`?

Comment: using jackson. and for setting default @RequestParam(value = "mode", required = false, defaultValue = "ALL"), this will help

Comment: This is a regular `@RequestParam` that doesn't use the json serialization but rather plain request parameter binding. So you would need a custom converter for that, a `String` to `EmployeeMode` converter. For the default you could set `ALL` as the default value (you can then remove `required=false` as that is then implied).

Comment: Have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24157817/jackson-databind-enum-case-insensitive)

Comment: @Jens I read that and tried. but not worked out for me

Comment: @Jens he is binding a regular parameter not deserializing a JSON body, so trying to solve this with configuring JSON (de)serializers or Jackson or Gson won't help a bit as that isn't being used at all when binding request parameters.

Answer (score 5):

You can handle it by implementing converter.

```
public class EmployeeModeConverter implements Converter<String, EmployeeMode> {
    @Override
    public EmployeeMode convert(String source) {
        switch (source.toUpperCase()) {
            case "REGULAR": return EmployeeMode.Regular;
            case "TEMPROARY": return EmployeeMode.TEMPROARY;
            default: return EmployeeMode.ALL;
        }        
    }
}

@Configuration
public class Config extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(new EmployeeModeConverter());
    }
}
```

Comment: Careful with the WebMvcConfigurationSupport, it can have [huge consequences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17898606/1651107), better to use WebMvcConfigurer that has same addFormatters method