# Spring boot JsonCreator for Enum not working for request parameter in GET call

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I have written custom JsonCreator for enum

```
@GetMapping(value = "/path/{pathVar1}")
  public Response getValue(
      @PathVariable String pathVar1,
       @RequestParam(required = false, name = "type") MyEnum type)
```

Enum

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public enum MyEnum {

  A_12(Set.of("a", "12"));

  private Set<String> aliases;

  @JsonCreator
  public static MyEnum forValues(@JsonProperty("type") String type) {
    return Arrays.stream(MyEnum.values())
        .filter(s -> s.getAliases().stream().anyMatch(a -> StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(a, type)))
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("aa"));
  }
```

Its not considering jsoncreator for enum.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant MyEnum.12
```

Am I missing any thing.

Comment: How do you call the API?

Comment: @Jens we call with alias.     path/1?typr=12

Comment: Can you please add also the complete stacktrace

Answer (score 2):

`@RequestParam` does not use a jackson deserializer. So `@JsonCreator` is not used.

By default, Spring uses `Converter` to deserialize `@RequestParam` and `@PathVariable` values.

So if you want to convert path values, create a custom converter.

[Check out this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75053897/deserialize-requestparam-enum-case-insensitive-in-spring-boot-using-jackson/75053959#75053959) I hope it can help you.