# How to modify the ObjectMapper in JHipster project?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, jhipster

I am having trouble configuring the default ObjectMapper in JHipster to allow JsonViews and also setting to false the `FORCE_LAZY_LOADING` property of the `Hibernate4Module` module.

I have tried three things without success:

1) Create a `@Bean` using the `@Primary` annotation to replace the default bean:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ObjectMapper viewsObjectMapper(){ 
     ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
     Hibernate4Module hibernateModule = new Hibernate4Module(); 
     hibernateModule.configure(Hibernate4Module.Feature.FORCE_LAZY_LOADING, false);       mapper.registerModule(hibernateModule);
     mapper.disable(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION);
     return mapper;
 }
```

2) I modified the `@Bean` `Hibernate4Module` in the `DatabaseConfiguration` class as follows:

```
@Bean
public Hibernate4Module hibernate4Module() {
    Hibernate4Module hibernateModule = new Hibernate4Module();
    hibernateModule.configure(Hibernate4Module.Feature.FORCE_LAZY_LOADING, true);
    return hibernateModule;
}
```

3) And this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650196/how-to-configure-mappingjacksonhttpmessageconverter-while-using-spring-annotatio).

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it as stated in [Spring Boot's documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper). In Spring Boot, it is not necessary to declare the ObjectMapper in a `@Configuration` class that extends the `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`. JHipster creates a `@Configuration` class named WebConfigurer where you can put this code:

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper viewsObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.disable(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION);    
    Hibernate4Module hibernateModule = new Hibernate4Module();
    hibernateModule.configure(Hibernate4Module.Feature.FORCE_LAZY_LOADING, false);          
    objectMapper.registerModule(hibernateModule);       
    return objectMapper;
}

@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jackson2Converter() {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setObjectMapper(viewsObjectMapper());          
    return converter;
}
```