# spring rest app, can't get data from PUT

Tags: spring, rest

I have two methods in controller, this is handler request from client. I can't get request body of PUT. For send request i use Advanced Rest Client in Chrome.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addPupil", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void addPupil(Pupil pupil){
    System.out.println(pupil.toString());
}
```

Result in Advanced Rest Client:

> Status 200 OK Response does not contain any data.

**stdout**:

```
Pupil{address='is address', level='is level', group='is group', last='is last', name='is name'}
```

But problem with this method, i can't get pupil object!

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/changePupil/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public void changePupil(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Pupil pupil){
    System.out.println("id: "+id);
    System.out.println(pupil.toString());
}
```

Result in Advanced Rest Client:

> Status 200 OK Response does not contain any data.

**stdout:**

```
id: 2
Pupil{address='null', level='null', group='null', last='null', name='null'}
```

Comment: What are your requests? We can't help you if you do not provide enough information.

Comment: Request: 

`name=name&last=last&level=level&group=group&address=address`

i send request with Advanced Rest Client, i choice PUT or POST and add param

Answer (score 0):

you should use `@RequestBody`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/changePupil/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public void changePupil(@PathVariable("id") Long id,@RequestBody Pupil pupil){
    System.out.println("id: "+id);
    System.out.println(pupil.toString());
}
```

Comment: if i use @RequestBody i get error
`{
timestamp: 1439472233893
status: 415
error: "Unsupported Media Type"
exception: "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException"
message: "Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported"
path: "/changePupil/2"
}`

Answer (score 0):

Take an advantage of `@RestController` on your controller class instead of `@Controller` and specify the `MediaType` that your rest method consuming and you may have to register appropriate `HttpMessageConverter` too.

Ref: [How to configure MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter while using spring annotation-based configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650196/how-to-configure-mappingjacksonhttpmessageconverter-while-using-spring-annotatio)

Comment: I use `@RestController`, but i not understood as add `MediaType`

Comment: `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)` here consumes indicates that this method accepts only json media type.