# Spring JsonDeserializer not working for the type String

Tags: java, spring, string, jackson, json-deserialization

I have a requirement to strip off all the special characters and control characters from the fields of type String in any of the Objects. Deserializer was registered but never executes during the runtime for **Strings**. 
I tried adding the same as an annotation `@JsonDeserialize(using = StringProcessorComponent.class)`, but the same issue.
It works for any other type like `Date`/`Long`. Please let me know if I am missing any.

Here is my Deserializer.

```
@JsonComponent
public class StringProcessorComponent extends JsonDeserializer<String> {
    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        JsonToken currentToken = p.getCurrentToken();

        if (currentToken.equals(JsonToken.VALUE_STRING)) {
            String text = MyStringProcessor.clean(p.getValueAsString());
            return text;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To override default deserialisers you could use `SimpleModule`. Also, when you want to extend default implementation if possible you can extend default deserialisers. In your case you can extend `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer` class. See below example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringJoiner;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SimpleModule stringModule = new SimpleModule("String Module");
        stringModule.addDeserializer(String.class, new CustomStringDeserializer());

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(stringModule);

        String json = "{\"firstName\":\"  Tom \",\"lastName\":\"  Long \"}";

        CustomStringPojo customStringPojo = mapper.readValue(json, CustomStringPojo.class);
        System.out.println(customStringPojo);
    }
}

class CustomStringDeserializer extends StringDeserializer {
    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        String text = super.deserialize(p, ctxt);
        //clean up value
        return text.trim();
    }
}

class CustomStringPojo {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

Above code prints:

```
CustomStringPojo{firstName='Tom', lastName='Long'}
```

Comment: Thanks, Mike. In addition to the above code following way of registering in Spring Boot made it work.



Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

 @Override
 public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  mapper.registerModule(stringProcessorModule());
 }
 
 public SimpleModule stringProcessorModule() {
  SimpleModule stringModule = new SimpleModule();
  stringModule.addDeserializer(String.class, new MyStringDeserializer());
  return stringModule;
 }

}

Comment: @Raj, yes, in `Spring Boot` application you need to register this module. You can do that on many different ways. Take a look at: [SpringBoot: Consume & Produce XML with a Custom Serializer + Deserializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58184442/springboot-consume-produce-xml-with-a-custom-serializer-deserializer), [How to enable 'ALLOW_NUMERIC_LEADING_ZEROS' feature to allow leading zeroes in...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55795970/how-to-enable-allow-numeric-leading-zeros-feature-to-allow-leading-zeroes-in-j). In case my answer was helpful consider to accept and upvote it.