# Spring boot generic String trim Serialization

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

I am trying to implement generic Spring trim serializer across application however its doesn't seems to be  working.
And if I manually put this serializer `@JsonSerialize(using = StringTrimmerSerializer.class)` on a particular field it does work not sure what i need to do to make it work throughout application without putting  it for all fields individually

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.boot.jackson.JsonComponent;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;

@JsonComponent
public class StringTrimmerSerializer extends JsonSerializer<String> {

  @Override
  public void serialize(String value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {

    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(value)) {
      value = value.trim();
    }
    gen.writeString(value);
  }

}
```

Update:

Tried registering serializer as well but same issue

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); //
        //mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        // mapper.configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, true);
        mapper.registerModule(new SimpleModule().addSerializer(String.class, new StringTrimmerSerializer()));
        return mapper;
    }

    /*
     * @Bean public Module customSerializer() { SimpleModule module = new
     * SimpleModule(); module.addSerializer(String.class, new
     * StringTrimmerSerializer()); return module; }
     */
}
```

Main Class package : `com.demo`
Serializer Package : `com.demo.config`

Spring boot Version - `2.2.5.RELEASE`
Jackson-databind - `2.10.2`

Comment: You need to register StringTrimmerSerializer serializer with the ObjectMapper

Comment: @Cassian - Thanks for reply . I tried already but same issue.

Comment: ..actually you don't (need to register): "The annotation (`@JsonComponent`) allows us to expose an annotated class to be a Jackson serializer and/or deserializer without the need to add it to the ObjectMapper manually."

Comment: ..i rather assume/guess (before&after update): component scanning problem!?

Comment: @xerx593 - Ideally it should work with JsonComponent however  its not working :(

Comment: @xerx593 - Any pointer to resolve this issue

Comment: ...to exclude my assumption/worries: what is the "package" of your Main-class?, what the package of your serializer?

Comment: (spring boot application component scans its own and sub packages (only) by default)

Comment: @xerx593 - Please find update

Comment: hmm, (unfortunately) packages/scanning is not the issue.

Comment: what version of Jackson do you use?

Comment: mabey you need to extend StdSerializer instead of JacksonSerializer

Comment: @Cassian - Tried StdSerializer  as well

Comment: String are Serialized with Jackson`s StringSeriallier so you need to override StringSeriallier`s serialize method

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Spring JsonDeserializer not working for the type String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60724970/spring-jsondeserializer-not-working-for-the-type-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve by registering custom serializer to jaskcosn's default object mapper rather than creating a new reference of ObjectMapper.

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new SimpleModule().addSerializer(String.class, new StringTrimmerSerializer()));
        converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        return converter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add constructors in StringTrimmerSerializer

```
  public StringTrimmerSerializer ()

  public StringTrimmerSerializer (Class<String> s) {
      super(s);
   }
```

Comment: I`m not sure if the second contructor is used at serialization

Comment: Thanks for reply. But that didn't help either :(