# Jackson Json deserialization of an object to a list

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, resttemplate

I'm consuming a web service using Spring's `RestTemplate` and deserializing with `Jackson`.

In my JSON response from the server, one of the fields can be either an object or a list. meaning it can be either `"result": [{}]` or `"result": {}`.

Is there a way to handle this kind of things by annotations on the type I'm deserializing to ? define the member as an `array[]` or `List<>` and insert a single object in case of the second example ?
Can I write a new `HttpMessageConverter` that will handle it ?

Comment: Try to send a map instead of List, if you set a Hashmap, you're gonna always receive the response { }.

Comment: @Mitsu not sure what you mean. I'm implementing the client side only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with a configuration flag in Jackson's `ObjectMapper`:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json()
    .featuresToEnable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
    .build();
```

Just set this `ObjectMapper` instance to your `RestTemplate` as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9381832/1876620), and in the class you are deserializing to, always use a collection, i.e. a `List`:

```
public class Response {

    private List<Result> result;

    // getter and setter
}
```

Comment: That sounds great, can I set this flag on specific fields ? I don't want to apply it on every object.

Comment: @Nati I don't believe you can apply it to specific fields. However, if you have a single field in your JSON and you know for sure that it will never be a collection, then you can have a single field attribute in your java `Response` class (i.e. not a `List`).

Comment: It worked ! the only thing you need to change is `ObjectMapper objectMapper = Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json().build();` instead of `new`ing the object, and then I'll accept the answer

Comment: @Nati Done. Also changed the way the flag was being set.

Answer (score 8):

Since you are using Jackson I think what you need is `JsonDeserializer` class   ([javadoc](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonDeserializer.html?is-external=true)).

You can implement it like this:

```
public class ListOrObjectGenericJsonDeserializer<T> extends JsonDeserializer<List<T>> {

    private final Class<T> cls;

    public ListOrObjectGenericJsonDeserializer() {
        final ParameterizedType type = (ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        this.cls = (Class<T>) type.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> deserialize(final JsonParser p, final DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        final ObjectCodec objectCodec = p.getCodec();
        final JsonNode listOrObjectNode = objectCodec.readTree(p);
        final List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
        if (listOrObjectNode.isArray()) {
            for (JsonNode node : listOrObjectNode) {
                result.add(objectCodec.treeToValue(node, cls));
            }
        } else {
            result.add(objectCodec.treeToValue(listOrObjectNode, cls));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

...

```
public class ListOrObjectResultItemJsonDeserializer extends ListOrObjectGenericJsonDeserializer<ResultItem> {}
```

Next you need to annotate your POJO field. Let's say you have classes like `Result` and `ResultItem`:

```
public class Result {

    // here you add your custom deserializer so jackson will be able to use it
    @JsonDeserialize(using = ListOrObjectResultItemJsonDeserializer.class)
    private List<ResultItem> result;

    public void setResult(final List<ResultItem> result) {
    this.result = result;
    }

    public List<ResultItem> getResult() {
        return result;
    }
}
```

...

```
public class ResultItem {

    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(final String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Now you can check your deserializer:

```
// list of values
final String json1 = "{\"result\": [{\"value\": \"test\"}]}";
final Result result1 = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json1, Result.class);
// one value
final String json2 = "{\"result\": {\"value\": \"test\"}}";
final Result result2 = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json2, Result.class);
```

`result1` and `result2` contain the same value.

Comment: Cool. can it be generic ? say something like 
`public List<T> deserialize(final JsonParser p, final DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {`
?

Comment: I changed it to generic. But you have to extend the generic base class and specify field type anyway.

Comment: result.add(objectCodec.treeToValue(node, cls)); // this is trying to parse the items of the list, also as lists. Is this correct?