# How do I use JAXB annotations with Spring RestTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jaxb

I'm trying to automatically deserialize XML formatted response using Spring's RestTemplate. I'm using Jackson's `jackson-dataformat-xml` module, for which Spring Boot is set to auto-configure. I want to use JAXB annotations in the class I want to deserialize to, but it won't seem to work. Here's a sample of what I want the class to look like:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Book")
public class Book {

    @XmlElement(name="Title")
    private String title;
    @XmlElement(name="Author")
    private String author;

}
```

This is based on the following XML sample:

```
<Book>
    <Title>My Book</Title>
    <Author>Me</Author>
</Book>
```

However, with class annotated like that above, the fields are always set `null`. I did some experiments and found out that the deserialization works if I use Jackson's `@JsonProperty` to annotate the child elements:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Book")
public class Book {

    @JsonProperty("Title")
    private String title;
    @JsonProperty("Author")
    private String author;

}
```

It works, but somehow I feel like it's kind of awkward. Is there a way to get the JAXB annotations work like in my first example?

Jackson provides [`jackson-module-jaxb-annotations`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations) module for the XML databinding to work with JAXB annotations. However, I'm not sure how to setup the `ObjectMapper` being used by `RestTemplate` to use this module.

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm actually trying to do the same

Comment: @dalvarezmartinez1 Yeah. Please see my solution below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To address this issue, I needed to register an instance of `JaxbAnnotationModule` to every `ObjectMapper` used by converters added to Spring's `RestTemplate`. The class is included in Jackson's [`jackson-module-jaxb-annotations`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations) module, which I added to my build through Gradle.

With the dependency added to my project, what I did next was to configure the `RestTemplate` used by my application. The `ObjectMapper` instances are being used by `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter`s configured automatically by Spring. I had to register `JaxbAnnotationModule` instance to each `ObjectMapper` used in every converter, so the first task was to find all `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter`s using:

```
//create module
JaxbAnnotationModule jaxbAnnotationModule = new JaxbAnnotationModule();

restTemplate.getMessageConverters().stream().filter(converter -> {
    return converter instanceof MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter;
})
```

Once I had all the relevant converters, I then registered the module to each of their `ObjectMappers`:

```
forEach(converter -> {
    ((MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter) converter)
            .getObjectMapper()
            .register(jaxbAnnotationModule);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

If someone still have to deal with this kind of issue, Springboot provide an elegant solution :

> Any beans of type com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module are automatically registered with the auto-configured Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder and are applied to any ObjectMapper instances that it creates. This provides a global mechanism for contributing custom modules when you add new features to your application.

So adding this in one of your configuration class should be enough:

```
@Bean
public Module jaxbModule() {
    return new JaxbAnnotationModule();
}
```

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper

Comment: This worked when so many other tweaks failed. This is especially useful when using xjc and it's impossible to tweak the annotations.

Answer (score 2):

If solution by @Psycho Punch still not working for you, This is another alternative:

- add `com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml` dependency.
- use XmlMapper instead of ObjectMapper to your `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter`. For example:

  ```
  XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
  xmlMapper.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());

  forEach(converter -> {
      ((MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter) converter).setObjectMapper(xmlMapper)
  });
  ```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that in second case Spring simply ignores root level JAXB annotation, because by default Jackson will resolve name of the class properly.

In order to use JAXB annotations you have to use library `jackson-xc`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

These artilces may be also useful:

1) http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJAXBAnnotations

2) http://springinpractice.com/2011/12/06/jackson-json-jaxb2-xml-spring

3) [How can we configure the internal Jackson mapper when using RestTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381665/how-can-we-configure-the-internal-jackson-mapper-when-using-resttemplate)

Comment: I missed adding a few details regarding this in my question. However, `jackson-xc` is actually pretty outdated now, and the current module to add JAXB support to Jackson's XML databind is the [`jackson-module-jaxb-annotations`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations). My problem is I'm not sure how to setup the `ObjectMapper` being used by `RestTemplate` to use this module.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381665/how-can-we-configure-the-internal-jackson-mapper-when-using-resttemplate

Comment: I've tried registering the module via `registerModule()` method of `ObjectMapper` but I'm still getting `null` values in the object's fields.