# Spring resttemplate together with jaxb - ignore null elements

Tags: xml, spring, xsd, jaxb, resttemplate

I have a XSD file form which I generate a POJO using JAXB.

Something like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

  <xs:element name="XYZ">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="A" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="B" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
```

From that I got generated:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "a",
    "b",
    
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "XYZ")
public class XYZ {

    @XmlElement(name = "A")
    protected String a;
    @XmlElement(name = "B")
    protected String b;
```

When I'm using rest template to send the request to rest service I want the element with empty/null values to be ignored. Recently I started to use a new version of some platform where versions of jaxb/spring/much more libs were updated.

```
HttpEntity<XYZ> requestHttpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(xyz);


    B response;

    try {
      ResponseEntity<B> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange("someAddress", HttpMethod.POST, requestHttpEntity, B.class);
      response = responseEntity.getBody();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      return null;
    }
```

Unfortunately, I can't convince the system to ignore the null values - do you have any experience with that? Important is that I can't change the POJO directly, only to have it generated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please add the relevant code so the question complies with a [mcve]. Are you sending an XML payload to a rest service?

Comment: Hi @LMC, thanks for the reaction - I added a code used to send the XML payload to the rest service.

Comment: The key here might be the code to generate the payload xyz. XSD is used to [describe and validate an xml](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_intro.asp) instance. It's probably that intance what you are serializing to the POJO. That could be the code causing the issue, not the code used to send the payload.

Comment: The payload is created like this: xyz XYZ = new XYZ(); xyz.setA("test"). Then I expect to have the XML in the payload that contains only the one element not the empty one.

Comment: That's a java object, not the payload. The payload is that object serialized to xml or json.

Comment: Is this the same issue? https://stackoverflow.com/q/41288036/2834978