# Jackson Mapping List of String or simple String

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, mapper

I'm trying to get some Json from an API and parse them into some POJO's to work with them but i have this case where i can get for a key a simple String or an arrayList of Strings.

The Json looks like this :

```
{
  "offerDisplayCategoryMapping": [
    {
      "offerKey": "EUICC_BASE_ACTIVATION_V01",
      "categoriesKeys": {
        "categoryKey": "Included"
      }
    },
    {
      "offerKey": "EUICC_BASE_ACTIVATION_V02",
      "categoriesKeys": {
        "categoryKey": "Included"
      }
    },
    {
      "offerKey": "EUICC_BASE_ACTIVATION_V03",
      "categoriesKeys": {
        "categoryKey": [
          "Option",
          "Included"
        ]
      }
    }]
}
```

I'm using Spring Rest to get the result from the API. I created a POJO that represents `categoriesKeys` with a `List<String>` that defines `categoryKey` and in my `RestTemplate` I defined an `ObjectMapper` where i enabled `DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY` for the case of simple strings but this doesn't work!!

Any suggestions?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you add your pojo(s) and your `RestTemplate` in the question

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In addition to global configuration already mentioned, it is also possible to support this on individual properties:

```
public class Container {
  @JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
  // ... could also add Feature.WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED
  public List<String> tags;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I have tried this with just jackson outside Spring and it works as expected with:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
```

Mind that `RestTemplate` registers a `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` with it's own `ObjectMapper`. [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9381832/1413133) for how to configure this `ObjectMapper`.

Answer (score 2):

Since it is a List of keys it will work. if in case property has single value and not in array like below
**DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY** will ensure deserializing single property as a array

```
{
    "CategoriesKeys":{
    "categoryKey":{
        "keys":"1"
        }
    }
}



@JsonRootName("CategoriesKeys")
    protected static class CategoriesKeys{

        private CategoryKey categoryKey;
//getters and setters 

}

protected static class CategoryKey{

        private List<String> keys;
//getters and setters 

}

TestClass: 

ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);

Output: 

{"CategoriesKeys":{"categoryKey":{"keys":["1"]}}}
```